# How to call SupportMapFragment in non activity files i.e. RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview

I want to create Iterative Map view. For which Im using RecyclerView.

I tried calling the activity method getSupportFragmentManager() using context that I initialised in constructor of my adapter. But it's not working.

**template.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="256dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="29-18-2019 5:30"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_single_history"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<HistoryModel> dataList;

public HistoryAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<HistoryModel> dataList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.dataList = dataList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_single, viewGroup, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }
}
}
```

I want to know how to initialise google maps in non activity java files. As in above case.

Comment: May be better to use [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) or even [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite) instead of `SupportMapFragment`?

Comment: yup that worked thanks for help

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For RecyclerView Adapter is better to use [`MapView`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) in [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite) as in 
[that](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/LiteListDemoActivity.java) Official example of using `MapView` inside `RecyclerView`:

> ```
>     /**
>      * Holder for Views used in the {@link LiteListDemoActivity.MapAdapter}.
>      * Once the  the <code>map</code> field is set, otherwise it is null.
>      * When the {@link #onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap)} callback is received and
>      * the {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap} is ready, it stored in the {@link #map}
>      * field. The map is then initialised with the NamedLocation that is stored as the tag of the
>      * MapView. This ensures that the map is initialised with the latest data that it should
>      * display.
>      */
>     class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnMapReadyCallback {
>
>         MapView mapView;
>         TextView title;
>         GoogleMap map;
>         View layout;
>
>         private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
>             super(itemView);
>             layout = itemView;
>             mapView = layout.findViewById(R.id.lite_listrow_map);
>             title = layout.findViewById(R.id.lite_listrow_text);
>             if (mapView != null) {
>                 // Initialise the MapView
>                 mapView.onCreate(null);
>                 // Set the map ready callback to receive the GoogleMap object
>                 mapView.getMapAsync(this);
>             }
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
>             MapsInitializer.initialize(getApplicationContext());
>             map = googleMap;
>             setMapLocation();
>         }
>
>         /**
>          * Displays a {@link LiteListDemoActivity.NamedLocation} on a
>          * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap}.
>          * Adds a marker and centers the camera on the NamedLocation with the normal map type.
>          */
>         private void setMapLocation() {
>             if (map == null) return;
>
>             NamedLocation data = (NamedLocation) mapView.getTag();
>             if (data == null) return;
>
>             // Add a marker for this item and set the camera
>             map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(data.location, 13f));
>             map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(data.location));
>
>             // Set the map type back to normal.
>             map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
>         }
>
>         private void bindView(int pos) {
>             NamedLocation item = namedLocations[pos];
>             // Store a reference of the ViewHolder object in the layout.
>             layout.setTag(this);
>             // Store a reference to the item in the mapView's tag. We use it to get the
>             // coordinate of a location, when setting the map location.
>             mapView.setTag(item);
>             setMapLocation();
>             title.setText(item.name);
>         }
>     }
> ```

[Here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/res/layout/lite_list_demo_row.xml) you can find `MapView` layout settings for that case:

> ```
> <!-- MapView in lite mode. Note that it needs to be initialised
>      programmatically before it can be used. -->
> <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
>     android:id="@+id/lite_listrow_map"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="150dp"
>     map:liteMode="true" map:mapType="none" />
> ```